# processes all pre processed records again from Kafka when restart Storm

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I'm reading data from Kafka consumer to Storm spout. But, when i restart Storm it also read previously processed records from Kafka.
On restart I don't want to process previously processed records.
Here is my code :

```
public class KafkaStormSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SpoutConfig kafkaSpoutConfig = new SpoutConfig(hosts, topic, "/" + topic, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        kafkaSpoutConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());

        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
        builder.setSpout("kafka-spout", new KafkaSpout(kafkaSpoutConfig));
        builder.setBolt("word-spitter", new SplitBolt()).shuffleGrouping("kafka-spout");

        LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
        cluster.submitTopology("KafkaStormSample", config, builder.createTopology());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along with a **static UUID** you can use `StormSubmitter` to submit topologies to run on the Storm cluster. More info [here](https://storm.apache.org/releases/current/Running-topologies-on-a-production-cluster.html)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the random UUID you're using for SpoutConfig. Instead, pick a fixed string and use it every time.

Unrelated: You shouldn't be writing new code using `storm-kafka`. Use `storm-kafka-client` instead.

Comment: I tried with a fixed string but it didn't work. Still it processes all pre processed records. Is it something related to `LocalCluster` as once the service is restarted it processes previous records?

Comment: Don't use LocalCluster for production workloads. Yes, it's because LocalCluster runs with an embedded Zookeeper, so when you restart the cluster all state is wiped.

Comment: Yes, the problem was with `LocalCluster`. Now for production environment i am using `StormSubmitter` and it maintains state of records perfectly.